# How to read multiple line elements in Spark?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

When you read a file in Spark using **sc.textfile**, it gives you elements, where each element is a separate line. However, I want each element to consist of N number of lines. I can't use delimiters either because there is none in that file. So, how can I make spark give me multiple line elements?

And I'm interested in doing so using the **NLineInputFormat** class. Is that possible to do so in Spark? I can see examples of that for MapReduce, but I don't have any clue how that would translate to in Spark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to process multi line input records in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541637/how-to-process-multi-line-input-records-in-spark)

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I want to do it using the NLineInputFormat class. That is how my question is different.

Comment: are those hadoop files?

Comment: Yes, Hadoop files because they reside in the HDFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are getting the files from hadoop. You should be able to do it like this:

```
val records = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hadoopConf,classOf[NLineInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text])
```

Here's the [API doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopRDD(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how do you specify the number of lines?

Comment: In the hadoop config, just like if you were using it in MapReduce

Comment: Would something like this be correct? val c = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration);
c.set("lineinputformat.linespermap", 1000);

Comment: Yeah iirc that worked for me. Try it out and comment if something changed and it doesnt work.