# How can I parse this raw transactional log data in a Spark DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to process the Raw data with Spark 1.6 such that the first row shows up as a separate column along with rest of its corresponding rows. The first row will always have a 3 digit number followed by its corresponding rows which will always have a 8 digit number. However, the number of corresponding rows can vary. Here is a dummy example of Raw Data and desired output. How can I code this?

Raw Data

765
11111111
22222222
33333333
456
66666666
88888888

Desired output

765 11111111
765 22222222
765 33333333
456 66666666
456 88888888

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052480/how-to-read-multiple-line-elements-in-spark ?

Comment: Your best bet is probably to create a custom hadoop input format. Probably similar to NLineInputFormat as @the.malkolm suggested, but I don't think that will work if your number of rows is variable. You'll likely need to roll your own.

Comment: Will you be interested in s Spark Scala RDD implementation?

Comment: @marios Sure, thanks!

Comment: I am working on a solution, unless someone else replies I will post it in few hours.

Comment: @marios Great. If you happen to have a Spark Python implementation as well, that'll be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to try to solve this problem per partition. This works great as long as each partition starts with a 3-digit number. If a partition doesn't have a 3-digit number we need to find the last 3-digit number of the previous partition.

First we need some utility functions:

1. The first (last3dig) finds the last 3-digit number of each partition. This will help us to have an initial 3-digit number for those partitions that don't start with one. If we apply this to each partition we get a list of such 3-digit numbers. Each element is the last 3-digit of its corresponding partition if it exists, else None.
2. The second (fillGaps) takes care of properly filling the gaps of the list of last 3-digits (from previous step). So if we have `Some(1), None, None, Some(4)` it will make it `Some(1), Some(1), Some(1), Some(4)`.
3. The third (trasnformRow) will go over the initial RDD and use the utilities functions we created to populate the resulting RDD.

```
// Finds the last 3-digit number in a Stream (RDD partition)
def last3dig(x: Stream[String]): Option[String] = {
    def help(y: Stream[String], sofar: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
      y match {
        case h #:: tl => if(h.length == 3) help(tl, Some(h)) else help(tl, sofar)
        case Stream.Empty => sofar
      }
    }
    help(x, None)
  }

 def fillGaps(data: Vector[(Int, Option[String])] ): Vector[(Int, Option[String])] =     
    data.foldLeft(Vector.empty[(Int,Option[String])]){ 
       case (col,n) => if(n._2.isEmpty) (n._1, col.head._2) +: col else n +: col
 }

def trasnformRow(x: Stream[String], filler: String): Stream[String] = x match {
     case h #:: tl =>              
        if( h.length != 3 ) 
           s"$h $filler" #:: trasnformRow(tl, filler) 
        else 
            trasnformRow(tl, h) // update the filler
     case Stream.Empty => x
 }




// toy data
val d = Seq(765, 11111111, 22222222, 33333333, 456, 66666666, 88888888).map(_.toString)
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(d,2)

val mappings = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { 
    case(i,iter) => Iterator( (i, last3dig(iter.toStream)) ) 
}.collect().toVector

val filledMappings = fillGaps(mappings)

val mm = sc.broadcast(filledMappings.toMap)

val finalResult = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { 
   case (i,iter) => trasnformRow(iter.toStream, if(i>0) mm.value(i-1).get else "").toIterator 
}.collect() // remove collect() for large dataset
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Do you also happen to have a Python implementation that you can share?