# How to define multiple Custom Delimiter for input file in spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

The default input file delimiter while reading a file via Spark is newline character(\n). It is possible to define a custom delimiter by using "textinputformat.record.delimiter" property.

But, Is it possible to specify multiple delimiter for the same file ?

Suppose a file has following content :

```
COMMENT,A,B,C
COMMENT,D,E,
F
LIKE,I,H,G
COMMENT,J,K,
L
COMMENT,M,N,O
```

I want to read this file with delimiter as COMMENT and LIKE instead of newline character.

Although, i came up with an alternative if multiple delimiters are not allowed in spark.

```
val ss = SparkSession.builder().appName("SentimentAnalysis").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val sc = ss.sparkContext
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "COMMENT")
val rdd = sc.textFile("<filepath>")
val finalRdd = rdd.flatmap(f=>f.split("LIKE"))
```

But still, i think it will better to have multiple custom delimiter. Is it possible in spark ? or do i have to use the above alternative ?

Comment: I think this is only possible by creating a custom textinputformat

Comment: creating a custom **textinputformat** will help specify only a single type of delimiter at a time. Can it be used to define multiple delimiters also ? Can you kindly provide a sample of what you have in mind ?

Comment: no you can define the input format to use anything you want.  You need to write the code yourself though.  I've done it once before, it's hard finding a good tutorial, I used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27564697/5638835 as I guide when I did it

Comment: Thanks @puhlen. The post you provided did help me in writing custom textinputformat with two delimiters. I will post the answer here. Thanx a lot again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the above issue by creating a custom TextInputFormat class that splits on two types delimiter strings. The post pointed by @puhlen in the comments was a great help. Find below the code snippet which i used :

```
class CustomInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {
  override def createRecordReader(inputSplit: InputSplit,  taskAttemptContext: TaskAttemptContext): RecordReader[LongWritable, Text] = {
    return new ParagraphRecordReader();
  }
}
class ParagraphRecordReader extends RecordReader[LongWritable, Text] {
  var end: Long = 0L;
  var stillInChunk = true;

  var key = new LongWritable();
  var value = new Text();

  var fsin: FSDataInputStream = null;
  val buffer = new DataOutputBuffer();
  val tempBuffer1 = MutableList[Int]();
  val tempBuffer2 = MutableList[Int]();

  val endTag1 = "COMMENT".getBytes();
  val endTag2 = "LIKE".getBytes();

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  override def initialize(inputSplit: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputSplit, taskAttemptContext: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext) {
    val split = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit];
    val conf = taskAttemptContext.getConfiguration();
    val path = split.getPath();
    val fs = path.getFileSystem(conf);

    fsin = fs.open(path);
    val start = split.getStart();
    end = split.getStart() + split.getLength();
    fsin.seek(start);

    if (start != 0) {
      readUntilMatch(endTag1, endTag2, false);
    }
  }

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  override def nextKeyValue(): Boolean = {
    if (!stillInChunk) return false;

    val status = readUntilMatch(endTag1, endTag2, true);

    value = new Text();
    value.set(buffer.getData(), 0, buffer.getLength());
    key = new LongWritable(fsin.getPos());
    buffer.reset();

    if (!status) {
      stillInChunk = false;
    }

    return true;
  }

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  override def getCurrentKey(): LongWritable = {
    return key;

  }


  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  override def getCurrentValue(): Text = {
    return value;
  }

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  @throws(classOf[InterruptedException])
  override def getProgress(): Float = {
    return 0;
  }

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  override def close() {
    fsin.close();
  }

  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  def readUntilMatch(match1: Array[Byte], match2: Array[Byte], withinBlock: Boolean): Boolean = {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (true) {
      val b = fsin.read();
      if (b == -1) return false;

      if (b == match1(i)) {
        tempBuffer1.+=(b)
        i = i + 1;
        if (i >= match1.length) {
          tempBuffer1.clear()
          return fsin.getPos() < end;
        }
      } else if (b == match2(j)) {
        tempBuffer2.+=(b)
        j = j + 1;
        if (j >= match2.length) {
          tempBuffer2.clear()
          return fsin.getPos() < end;
        }
      } else {
        if (tempBuffer1.size != 0)
          tempBuffer1.foreach { x => if (withinBlock) buffer.write(x) }
        else if (tempBuffer2.size != 0)
          tempBuffer2.foreach { x => if (withinBlock) buffer.write(x) }
        tempBuffer1.clear()
        tempBuffer2.clear()
        if (withinBlock) buffer.write(b);
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Use the following class in while reading file from filesystem and your file will get read with two delimiters as required. :)

```
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("<filepath>", classOf[ParagraphInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], sc.hadoopConfiguration)
```